# notifyDataSetChanged() not updating UI

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-livedata

I want to display new list of items retrieved from ViewModel in custom RecyclerView.Adapter. To do so I pass the retrieved list to adapter and invoke `notifyDataSetChanged()`, but nothing changes on the UI.

I've debugged code and adapter's list had 1 element (UI displayed 1 element), new retrieved list had 2 elements - after setting new list in adapter and invoking `notifyDataSetChanged()` UI didn't change, but should append that 1 element.

Fragment's code:

```
trip_details_participantsList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
trip_details_participantsList.adapter = userBriefAdapter

tripsDetailsViewModel.getTripParticipants(tripId).observe(this, Observer {participants ->
   tripsDetailsViewModel.getUsersBriefs(participants.map { x -> x.userId }).observe(this, Observer{ users ->
       userBriefAdapter.setData(users)
   })
})
```

Custom Adapter and ViewHolder:

```
class UserBriefAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<UserBriefViewHolder>() {
   private var users: List<UserBrief> = mutableListOf()

   fun setData(items: List<UserBrief>){
      this.users = items
      notifyDataSetChanged()
   }

   override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: UserBriefViewHolder, position: Int) = 
      holder.bind(users[position])

   override fun getItemCount() = users.size

   override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): UserBriefViewHolder {
      val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
      return UserBriefViewHolder(inflater, parent)
   }
}

class UserBriefViewHolder(inflater: LayoutInflater, parent: ViewGroup) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(inflater.inflate(
   R.layout.trip_details_list_item, parent, false)) {

   private var profilePictureImageView: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.trips_details_profile_image)

   fun bind(userBrief: UserBrief){
      Picasso.get()
        .load(userBrief.profilePictureUrl)
        .into(profilePictureImageView)
    }
}
```

I've read existing topics about it, but every accepted solution is something like my adapter's `setData()` function with `notifyDataSetChanged()`. I've also tried to set new instance of UserBriefAdapter to RecyclerView each time observed values changed, but results were the same. When I go back and forth the view, then it correctly displays the elements, but I want to achieve this without changing the view.

Answer (score 0):

It could be an issue of threading.  Try to post a runnable to the main thread in your observer callback:

```
 tripsDetailsViewModel.getUsersBriefs(participants.map { x -> x.userId }).observe(this, Observer{ users ->
     view?.post { userBriefAdapter.setData(users) }
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work either. I edited Fragment's code in my question, because what I really do is calling  ```tripsDetailsViewModel.getUsersBriefs``` each time ```participants``` changes. I don't know if this changes something.

Answer (score 0):

Done some more debugging and figured out that `notifyDataSetChanged()` wasn't the problem. I was passing wrong `profilePictureUrl` to `UserBriefViewHolder`, so Picasso library doesn't fetch an image and in consequence UI wasn't updated.